# com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener's LocationChanged not called

Tags: android

I am creating a service in which I request for locationUpdate .But
     LocationChanged callback is called only when the service first started after that is not called.Location changed should be invoked on 2km changed .Is I am doing something wrong

```
       package com.example.qwerty;
     import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;

        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;

        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;

        import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;

        import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

        import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;




        import android.os.IBinder;


        //Location Callback
        public class LocationService extends Service  implements ConnectionCallbacks,OnConnectionFailedListener  {

         private class locationListener  implements LocationListener   {

            public void addLocation(String loc){
                SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences(Contant.MYPREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor edit = pref.edit();  
                String s ="";
                if(pref.contains("location")){
                      s =    pref.getString("location", "");
                     } 
                     s  = s + loc;
                     edit.putString("location",s).commit();
                    }

        public void getAddress( final double latitude , final double longitude){
                new AsyncTask<Double, Void, String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(Double...params){ 
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(LocationService.this,Locale.getDefault());
                        String result ="";
                        List<Address> addressList =null;
                        try {
                            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                                    params[0], params[1], 1);
                         if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                            Address address = addressList.get(0);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                            }
                            sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                            sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                            sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                            result = sb.toString();
                        }
                    }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                              result =e.toString(); 
                              result  = result + " " +  latitude +  "  "+  longitude;
                        } 

                        return result;
                    }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
                           addLocation(result); 
                        }
                  }.execute(latitude , longitude);
        } 
         @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if(NetworkState.isNetConnected(LocationService.this)) {
                    getAddress(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());                                                        
                }else{
                    addLocation(" lat " +  location.getLatitude()+ "  long " + location.getLongitude());
                } 
            }

            }


         GoogleApiClient client  =  null;
                public LocationService() {

                }

            @Override   
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                SharedPreferences pref= getSharedPreferences(Contant.MYPREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
                client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                 .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                 .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                 .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                 .build();  
                 client.connect();


               return START_STICKY;


            }
              @Override
                public void onDestroy() {


             }

             @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
                LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                mLocationRequest.setInterval(420000);
                mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(1000);

                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(client, mLocationRequest , new locationListener());

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {


            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got another solution that work for me.may be it helps other in near future.

1. Set up alaram for n minutes
2. On this alaram set a broadcast.When you receive broadcast start a service which will get the current location.
3. After getting location stop that service.
4. The same thing goes on and on.